# Access application gets full screen on double click from taskbar button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I developed a tool in MS Access where I hide the top pane of Access so that user can only close the application by clicking close button on the pop up form. That leaves no way for the user to minimize or restore Access window as is required.
However, the problem comes when a user clicks the Acess button twice from the taskbar on windows 10, it gets into full screen mode and user cannot restore it unless by closing and reopening the application. Can someone please provide a solution to this?

Comment: The F11 key will toggle MSACCESS full screen

Comment: What OS and Office version? Taskbar allows minimze and close too, Alt-F4, task manager can close app. Why are you trying to prevent close? Also you didn't complete the [tour] ans should read [ask] and related to improve question.

Comment: Users can hover mouse on the task bar, and when the small preview window appears, move mouse into that preview window, and choose restore, or maximize. So, you might not need any code here.